# Is reusing same process name in loop situation possibly generate zombie process?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

My script has to run over a day and its core cycle runs 2-3 times per a minute. I used multiprocessing to give a command simultaneously and each of them will be terminated/join within one cycle.

But in reality I found the software end up out of swap memory or computer freezing situation, I guess this is caused by accumulated processes. I can see on another session while running program, python PID abnormally increasing by time. So I just assume this must be something process thing. What I don't understand is how it happens though I made sure each cycle's process has to be finished on that cycle before proceed the next one.

so I am guessing, actual computing needs more time to progress 'terminate()/join()' job, so I should not "reuse" same object name. Is this proper guessing or is there other possibility?

```
def function(a,b):
    try: 
         #do stuff # audio / serial things
    except:
         return

flag_for_2nd_cycle=0

for i in range (1500):  # main for running long time

     #do something

     if flag_for_2nd_cycle==1:
         while my_process.is_alive():
             if (timecondition) < 30: # kill process if it still alive
                 my_process.terminate()
                 my_process.join()

     flag_for_2nd_cycle=1

     my_process=multiprocessing.process(target=function, args=[c,d])
     my_process.start()

     #do something and other process jobs going on, for example

     my_process2 = multiprocessing.process() ##*stuff

     my_process2.terminate()
     my_process2.join()
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? You are basically running functions in sequence in another process.

Comment: @RolandSmith I have to control three projection machines simultaneously and each one has multiple functions which also has to run continuously, also controlled by serial communication. Originally I was keep producing new process within cycle now you reminding me that I should run only three process whole duration but with child threads for its own functions run simultaneously. Tricky part for me would be communication between processes and handling audio streams. And still I doubt even though I run fixed processes situation, wouldn't be kind of same situation happens with multi threads..

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, you are controlling three projectors over serial ports.

The simplest way to do that would be to simply open three serial connections (using [`pySerial`](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)). Then run a loop where you check for available data each of the connections and if so, read and process it. Then you send commands to each of the projectors in turn.
Depending on the speed of the serial link you might not need more than this.